# mySQL table, primary key

Tags: mysql, relational-database, primary-key

I have a table which is used for two purposes. One purpose is for calculation that is done every 5 seconds by running a PHP cron job. For this purpose I need a primary key that is a combination of about 5 fields. With this primary key the cron job runs really effectively and really fast. Then there is the second purpose of the table and that is to retrieve data to display on the web-page after user signs in. For that purpose, totally different primary key would be needed. The one that I use for cron makes it slow. I am tempted to create two tables with identical fields and data but with different primary key. I know it would add a lot of overhead but the website will be really quick and responsive. Is that something that would be recommended?

Comment: Look into using an auto_increment column to use for primary keys. It is much more efficient than using multi-column keys.

Comment: No, not in my case. For the calculation I need to find a product that I don't know the auto-increment number of (the lowest price product of certain category, and of certain specs). That's why using product_cat+specs1+spec2 etc is the most effective key. Using auto-increment makes mysql check almost all rows to find what I am looking for (veeery slow). My primary key can find it by checking like 20 rows (veeery fast).

Comment: Yes, but that is not called a "primary key"; it is a "composite" key. It would be helpful to see the table definitions (including indexes) and sql, especially if you can create a SQLFIDDLE.COM example that includes some relevant data.

Comment: Plaese disregard this comment.

Comment: Disregard which comment? the first one or the second one?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index on whatever combination of fields you need.

In general, I prefer an auto-incremented integer primary key on tables.  Very useful.

You can have such an index and then build two more indexes on the other columns

```
create index table_col1_col2_col3_col4_col5 on table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);
```

for the first index.  If you like, you can make this a `unique` index and the database will then enforce uniqueness among rows for these five columns.  Then you can create another index for surfing the table in another way:

```
create index table_col6_col7 on table(col6, col7);
```

This can be used for retrieval.

There is some overhead to maintaining the indexes on `insert`/`update`/`delete` operations.  You would want to test in your environment to see if this is a problem (typically it is not).